# Exception : Error creating bean with name 'richBean'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I have an error while I'm instantiating an Event.
I searched on different forum and saw that it could be the version of tomcat but I'm actually using the 7.042 version and the problem is fixed.

The problem is here i think but i can't find how to fix it :

```
   @javax.inject.Inject
    Event<String> pushEvent;
```

Here is my error :

```
    mars 17, 2014 10:13:58 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy       handleRenderException
    Grave: Error Rendering View[/test.xhtml]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name      'richBean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.enterprise.event.Event org.barApp.web.jsf.RichBean.pushEvent; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.enterprise.event.Event] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @org.richfaces.cdi.push.Push(subtopic=, topic=pushCdi)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:99)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:158)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.barApp.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: javax.enterprise.event.Event org.barApp.web.jsf.RichBean.pushEvent; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.enterprise.event.Event] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @org.richfaces.cdi.push.Push(subtopic=, topic=pushCdi)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.enterprise.event.Event] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @org.richfaces.cdi.push.Push(subtopic=, topic=pushCdi)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 75 more
```

Here is my beanClass :

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.richfaces.application.push.TopicKey;
import org.richfaces.application.push.TopicsContext;
import org.richfaces.cdi.push.Push;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMappings;

@ManagedBean(name = "richBean")
@javax.inject.Named
@Component(value = "richBean")
@Scope(value = "session")
@URLMappings(mappings = { @URLMapping(id = "rich", pattern = "/test", viewId = "/test.xhtml") })
public class RichBean {

    public static final String PUSH_CDI_TOPIC = "pushCdi";

    private String message;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    @Push(topic = PUSH_CDI_TOPIC)
    Event<String> pushEvent;


    /**
     * Sends message.
     *
     * @param message to send
     */
    public void sendMessage() {
        System.out.println("***COUCOU***");
        pushEvent.fire(message);
        message = "";
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

My test.xhtml :

```
    <ui:composition template="/pages/template/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
    xmlns:b="http://richfaces.org/sandbox/bootstrap"
    lang="fr">

    <ui:define name="body">

    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="4">
            <h:outputLabel value="Message:" />
            <h:inputText id="messageInput" styleClass="message" value="#{richBean.message}">
            </h:inputText>

            <a4j:commandButton value="Send" action="#{richBean.sendMessage}"
                execute="@form" render="messageInput" />

            <rich:messages for="messageInput" />
        </h:panelGrid>


    </h:form>

    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <a4j:push address="pushCdi"
                ondataavailable="jQuery('&lt;li /&gt;').prependTo('#messages').text(event.rf.data)" />

            <ul id="messages" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: issue is with with this `Event<String> pushEvent` have you defined anywhere this bean?

Comment: well this is coming from : javax.enterprise.event.Event

Answer (score 0):

You did not have any bean with name "richBean". Make sure you have missed out the bean definition.

Comment: Sorry,
RichBean is actually the name of my class.

Comment: I updated my post , do you have an idea of the problem of the @Inject ?

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate your `CustomClass` class with `@javax.inject.Named` annotation in order to be able to inject it in your `RichBean` bean:

```
package my.package;

import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
public class CustomClass {
...
}
```

**Note:** Make sure to enable the annotation-based-scan in order to let your dependency manager discover your beans by adding `<context:component-scan>` tag in spring context file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

  ...
  <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name" />
  ...

</beans>
```

Also I can't see no basic advantage for using both `@javax.inject.Named` and `@org.springframework.stereotype.Component` annotations. You should keep either of them for beans injection.

Comment: Still doesn't work with this annotation I still have this "Injection of autowired dependencies failed".
Moreover when i check console on firefox i have also : "TypeError: jQuery.atmosphere is undefined"
What do you think i should do ?

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace and the error detected into your browser should be related to a missing import of some script not to the main thread issue.

Comment: Have you added `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name" />` in the spring context descriptor?

Comment: Yes i added it.
Here the full stack trace :
http://pastebin.com/bPYFVjrX
and here is the error detected into my browser :
15:17:04,096 GET http://localhost:8180/barApp/test [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 134ms]
15:17:04,183 L'utilisation de « getUserData() » ou « setUserData() » est obsolète. Utiliser « WeakMap » ou « element.dataset » à la place. requestNotifier.js:64
15:17:04,719 GET http://localhost:8180/barApp/RES_NOT_FOUND [HTTP/1.1 404 Introuvable 2ms]
15:17:04,685 TypeError: jQuery.atmosphere is undefined packed.js:2261